# Access nth item when iterating Ember object array with for rather than forEach

Tags: ember.js

It made more sense in a particular case today to use a standard `for (i = 0..` loop rather than a `forEach`, but I realised I don't know how to access objects of an Ember Array by number.

So lets say we have:

```
var order = this.get('order');
var orderItems = order.get('orderItems');

orderItems.forEach(function(orderItem) {
  orderItem.set('price', 1000);
});
```

I thought I could do the equivalent as:

```
var order = this.get('order');
var orderItems = order.get('orderItems');

for (i = 0; i < orderItems.get('length'); i++) {
  orderItems[i].set('price', 1000);
}
```

but I get `orderItems[0] is undefined` etc.

How do I access the nth element in an ember array in js?

Comment: Did you tried using `objectAt` : http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_objectAt

Comment: That's what I was missing, if you would like to write that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember.js Array provides a `objectAt` method for accessing the nth element, which you can use for iteration.

Your updated code would look like :

```
var order = this.get('order');
var orderItems = order.get('orderItems');

for (i = 0; i < orderItems.get('length'); i++) {
  orderItems.objectAt(i).set('price', 1000);
}
```

Check out it's documentation here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_objectAt